# Highcharts overlapping tickIntervals in case of xAxis.breaks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using xAxis.breaks to conditionally apply the breaks on data plotting in the graph. I have `Start`,`Pause` and `Clear` buttons. When I click the start button the chart plotting starts (at 1 sec interval). Now, after sometime (say 10 secs) I click Pause button which pauses the chart plotting and then wait for say 5 secs. Now, click the start button again and since I am using xAxis.breaks with a breaksize of 1000 ms, the next point is plotted perfectly fine i.e. after 1 sec interval even if there is a time gap of more than 1 sec.

But, the tickPositions are overlapping. Can any one please help me with this. I suppose, I am doing something wrong with setExtremes.

Please suggest http://jsfiddle.net/roytirthadeep/pupk16ys/9/

Comment: Maybe better is use a [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) and prepare custom function for positioning ticks?